# Page redirection in multiple project under single solution

Tags: asp.net

I have a multiple web application under a single solution like this -

[image]

ODCPortal is my startup project. Now in ODCPortal home.aspx page in some button event, I am trying to redirect CSP_Home.aspx page. But I am getting The resource cannot be found error.
My code -

```
Response.Redirect(string.Format("http://{0}/CSP/CSP_Home.aspx",
                            Request.Url.Host));
Response.Redirect("~/ODCPortal/CSP/CSP_Home.aspx");
```

Nothing working for me. Please some one help me.
Thanks in advance
Gulrej

Comment: Can you browse to `CSP_Home.aspx` successfully or otherwise confirm that it should be found where you expect it?

Comment: Is that path can be viewed from a browser?
Is it configured right in IIS?

Comment: Which Web Server do you use for hosting of the projects?

Comment: My application still under development...so we have not hosted in any web server yet. I am trying to redirect the page from my local system.

Comment: And I am able to browse the CSP_Home.aspx page

Comment: Do I need any IIS configuration in my development system IIS??

Comment: Can some one please share any link where I can see any example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case two project are independent to each other, for redirection you must use full URL or you must host them on IIS and one of them virtual application of onther one.

For the IIS configuration see [ASP.NET and IIS Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [Deploying ASP.NET Websites on IIS 7.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28693/Deploying-ASP-NET-Websites-on-IIS-7-0)

Comment: So I need to host the entire solution in my local IIS?

Comment: And what will be the full URL here?

Comment: One more question when I debug my application from VS 2010, will it work?

Comment: The full URL is depend on your IIS configuration such as IP address binding, host header

Comment: Yes, you can debug it like before

Comment: For debugging websites on the IIS you can see [this](http://idosql.com/2011/05/25/181/)

Comment: I have tried...not working. Please suggest me some link where I can see some example.

Comment: Hi, Kambiz...it is working fine now Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @Gulrej Not complaining, just curious about why you didn't accept the answer while you mentioned its works for you? Accepting the right answer helps the other people to find the right solution faster and easier and increase your reputation also.

Comment: Sorry man..actually I didnt know how to accept the ans. Now I think I have done it.